# Move Already Added Annotation To NewLocation

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

I want to move added annotation to newlocation, below is the code and in else part i want to do that :

In previous code, new annotation is added and previous annotation is removed, but its get affected in degree of direction. So, i want to move annotation with out adding new annotation.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;
    if  (!newLocation)
        return;

    static BOOL annotationAdded = NO;

    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    self.previousLocation = oldLocation;

    if(self.currentLocation != nil)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location title:@"Current Location" subTitle:nil];
        if (!annotationAdded)
        {
            annotationAdded = YES;
            [self.myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        }
        else
        {
            // Here i want to move added annotation to newlocation coordinates 

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it works, is that you feed the map with annotations and then it fires the function that plot the annotations on the screen. Once it's on the screen, that is no way basically to move the annotation but to delete it and add a new one with new coordinates.